what is the fastest way to send transaction?
what's the fastest way to execute a lending transaction? I've tried using a private RPC URL from QuickNode, but it still takes 5-10 seconds. I'm using the send and confirm transaction method from Solana Web3js. If anyone knows how to solve this, please help us

For a user, your best bet is to go through an RPC configured with stake-weighted quality of service: https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/stake-weighted-qos
There are other mechanisms for transaction prioritization, by adding priority fees to your transaction (https://solana.com/docs/core/fees#prioritization-fee-best-practices) or through Jito bundles (https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/bundles).
If you're running a voting validator that has leader slots, then you can directly include your transaction during your leader slot.
